Deploying an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API
I am a newbie in ASP.NET. I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API. The application is to be published. On the production system (Windows) .NET Core Hosting Bundle is installed. An Apache server serves as a reverse proxy.
Among other things, the application consists of webapplication.exe, webapplication.dll and appsettings.json. It is started with dotnet webapplication.dll. Kestrel is used as server. It does work.
My question is, if this is a common practice, do I have to consider or do anything else?

When you publish with Core the runtime version of Core is deployed with the package.  Core will run with either Windows, MAC, or Linux.  The only issue you may have is with Credentials.  Most Systems are moving toward OAUTH2 authentication and not Windows Credentials
